# Electron and React; detecting electron api changes in react with electron remote

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am trying to change the style of a div tag dynamically when the electron window is maximized. In the code below I want the div class=resizer to display: none when the electron window is maximized.

In the electron api there is a .isMaximized() function call on the window variable. I am requiring the electron remote with: const remote = window.require('electron').remote. Then I remote.getCurrentWindow().

The issue is I can't thing of a way to trigger a way to listen if the window is maximized? I could use like a useEffect() react hook that checks window.isMaximized() every 1 seconds or so, but doesn't seem very optimized and a waste of resources.

Is there a better way to check this? I need a way to 'watch' for when the window becomes maximized.

```
const remote = window.require('electron').remote

const TitlebarDev = () => {

    const window = remote.getCurrentWindow()

    return (
        <div className="TitlebarDev">
            <div className="Title-BarDev">
                <div className="TitlebarDev-drag-region"></div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-icon">
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-menubar">
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-center">
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-windows-control">
                </div>
                <div
                    // Here is the div I need to change when the window is maximized; I just have a placeholder ternary function on it for concept.
                    style={true ? { display: 'none' } : {}}
                    className="resizer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default TitlebarDev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this after some time studying.
The issue was solved using electrons built-in event listeners on the BrowserWindow (win.) object.

Below in the code; the remote is imported with window.require('electron').remote. Then I save the CurrentWindow() object in a variable called 'window'. On that window variable you can call the .on method which can take the predefined event listeners built into electron. Using window.on('maximize', () => {})  / which is the 'maximize' event listener/ the callback function is ran whenever the window is maximized. On Electrons official API docs under BrowserWindow, there is a full list of event listeners.

Hopefully this can help others out in the future!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const remote = window.require('electron').remote

const TitlebarDev = () => {

    // React state
    const [isMaximized, setIsMaximized] = useState();

    // Electron currentwindow call with remote
    const window = remote.getCurrentWindow()

    // gets current state if maximized in real time
    window.on('maximize', () => {
        setIsMaximized(true)
    })

    // gets current state if unmaximzed in real time
    window.on('unmaximize', () => {
        setIsMaximized(false)
    })

    return (
        <div className="TitlebarDev">
            <div className="Title-BarDev">
                <div className="TitlebarDev-drag-region"></div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-icon">
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-menubar">
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-center">
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-windows-control">
                </div>
                <div
                    style={isMaximized ? { display: 'none' } : {}}
                    className="resizer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default TitlebarDev
```

EDIT: if anyone finds this, don't use "remote" anymore!! Use IPC now, as remote is slow and old. IPC is much much faster and their writing async/await syntax for it.

Comment: hello how do you use ipc? i mean like remote?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://nornagon.medium.com/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31) article we shouldn't use "remote" at all. The better way is to communicate with the renderer through [Sending Messages](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main/#sending-messages):

```
 mainWindow.on('maximize', () =>
   mainWindow?.webContents.send('window-maximized')
 );

 mainWindow.on('unmaximize', () =>
   mainWindow?.webContents.send('window-unmaximized')
 );
```

Then add handlers for these messages on the renderer side:

```
const onMaximized = () => setIsMaximized(true);
const onRestore = () => setIsMaximized(false);

useEffect(() => {
  ipcRenderer.on('window-maximized', onMaximized);
  ipcRenderer.on('window-unmaximized', onRestore);
}, []);
```